# Can you read the text in a certain Div vb.net

Tags: vb.net

I need  wondering if you read text in a certain div so when the html code says:

```
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
<div id="t" class="tee-tools" contenteditable="true" data-placeholder="Write a message (Enter to send)">xxxx</div>
</body>
</html>
```

get the text like xxxx in the code

Comment: Yes. Try an HTML Parser, or Regex.

Comment: give me code for vb.net

Comment: Nonono! Stack Overflow is not a code writing service. Do some research, and read [How to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Answer (score 0):

You Need HTMLAgilityPack.Dll first.

```
Imports System.Net
Imports System.IO

Public Class Form1
    Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        Dim page As String = GetPage("http://qrspace.com/rere.html")
        Dim dokuman = New HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument()
        dokuman.LoadHtml(GetPage(page))
        Dim title As HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlNodeCollection = dokuman.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//div[@class='tee-tools']")
        For Each titles In title
            MsgBox(titles.InnerText)
            'If titles.InnerText = "xxxx" Then
                'blablabla
            'End If
        Next
    End Sub
    Function GetPage(ByVal pageUrl As String) As String
        Dim s As String = pageUrl
        Try
            Dim request As HttpWebRequest = WebRequest.Create(s)
            Dim response As HttpWebResponse = request.GetResponse()
            Using reader As StreamReader = New StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream())
                s = reader.ReadToEnd()
            End Using
        Catch ex As Exception
        End Try
        Return s
    End Function
End Class
```

Comment: i want just write text like xxx in web page !

Comment: <div id="t" class="tee-tools" contenteditable="true" data-placeholder="Write a message (Enter to send)">SOME TEXT HERE</div>

Comment: my code great work. this is a parse your div. extract innerTEXT

Comment: No. It's a Desktop app. you need a ASP.NET Web form?

Comment: If you need parse div use this app but i don't understand what you want?

Comment: vb.net desktop app . but i want read and replace the text xxxx to zzzz for example

Comment: xxxx or zzzz this code getting all Text in a div from web page

Comment: i know cant save the edit but i want replace xxx to zzzz in div in web page understand me ? and thanks

Comment: Replace Only your desktop app not replace web page.

Comment: i want replace text in div in web page

Comment: in my program the text in web page its a messege and i want write the messege like xxxx not read text - write text in web page

Comment: write xxxx like in your web page

Comment: you have face book or somthing to be chat send you vedio or photo to my proplem !!

Comment: Change it? where your div address?

Comment: my fb: fb.com/hamza55

Comment: i want # open my app desktop web browser go to the web page open element edit xxxx to zzzz in element i know can save the edit - xxxx to zzzz when i open qrspace.com/rere.html

Comment: arabic email i wiil add you now